# Azure Virtual Machine creation issue using python

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I am creating the Azure VM using Python and I am selecting the VM Size of a Particular region and for a particular CPU and Memory using the following custom function code.

```
def list_vm_sizes_eq_cpu_memory(compute_client, region, cores, memory_MB,prefix):
    vm_sizes_list = compute_client.virtual_machine_sizes.list(location=region)
    vm_lists=[]    
    for vm_size in vm_sizes_list:
        if vm_size.number_of_cores == int(cores) and vm_size.memory_in_mb == int(memory_MB):            
            vm_lists.append(vm_size)
    
    return vm_lists
```

above function gives me the list of VM sizes and I pick the last record as the latest and create the VM using this size.

**But the issue I am facing is that by using the size sometimes VM is created successfully but sometimes it gives the Error of Operation Config**.

There is also an issue of Premium Disk and Accelerated Network. Some VM Size supports Premium Disk and Accelerated Network

**Is there any way to identify that all VM Parameters are correct before creating the Azure VM using Python.**

**Also is there any way to identify the correct VM size based on CPU, Memory, Support Premium Disk, and Support Accelerated Network in a region and will not give any error while creating the Azure VM using Python.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I know both Premium Disk and Accelerated Network just support the VM size, not all. And the `virtual_machine_sizes` cannot contain the message that which one supports Premium Disk and Accelerated Network. So I recommend you can create two lists to store all the VM size that support them, one for Premium Disk and one for Accelerated Network. When you list all the available VM size in the special region, you can check if the available size exists in both two lists, if yes, then append the VM size into the `vm_lists` that you use in the above code.

And the VM sizes support the Premium Disk, you can find the [VM sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes) and see it like this:

[image]

You can get VM sizes that support Accelerated Network [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli?toc=/azure/virtual-machines/linux/toc.json&bc=/azure/virtual-machines/linux/breadcrumb/toc.json#supported-vm-instances).

Comment: Thanks, Charles but the problem I am facing is I got the VM Size from the Code but when I create the VM, sometimes it is created and sometimes it is not and python did not provide the proper error message. Need to know if any way we can find in advance before creating the VM that all configuration is correct for creating the VM or not

Comment: @AmitKumar What do you mean all correct? What is the wrong thing do you think about the VM?

Comment: I mean to say that when I am creating the VM, I sometimes get the VM size is not supporting premium disk and it does not support accelerated network.

I need to know if I get this information that my VM configuration is not correct for deployment and I can modify and then deploy using python.

Comment: @AmitKumar So I suggest you create two lists include all the VM sizes that support the premium disk and accelerated network, then when you choose a VM size, you can check if it exists in both two lists.